# "InsecurePlatformWarning" while installing django

Tags: python, django

I am using:

-CentOS 6.6 on my Mac on virtual environment,

-Python 2.6.6
I am using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-centos-7) to install Django:

I am new to Python and Django and i found this tutorial easy to use so i was following the steps for Install through pip in a Virtualenv as i managed to install pip. it was working fine till i run pip install django command i got this output:

```
(djenv)[root@blue djProject]# pip install django
/root/djProject/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting django
/root/djProject/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached Django-1.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django-1.8.3
```

And after that when i try checking the version using django-admin --version command i got this error which i don't understand:

```
(djenv)[root@blue djProject]# clear; django-admin --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/djProject/djenv/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/root/djProject/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/root/djProject/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
  File "/root/djProject/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
    fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please help me with this error please.

Comment: Which error are you asking for help with?  The InsecurePlatform or the invalid syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the link that it says contains more information?

It says:

> If you encounter this warning, it is strongly recommended you upgrade to a newer Python version, or that you use pyOpenSSL as described in the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section.

Python 2.6.x is very old.